# Oracle Stand Alone Stored Procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I would like to create a stored procedure that will return all rows from a table in an Oracle database (Pretty much just a select * from). I have seen previous posts recommending to create a function or a package containing a procedure but I'm after a standalone procedure if it's possible.

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stored procedures do not return anything (functions return something).  Stored procedures can have `OUT` parameters

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE getAllEmps( p_rc OUT sys_refcursor )
AS
BEGIN
  OPEN p_rc
   FOR SELECT *
         FROM emp;
END;
```

Although you certainly can do this sort of thing, it is a relatively unusual way to structure your code.  You would almost never in a real system want to have standalone procedures outside of packages.